# Validation Failed when running bin/magento app:config:import

Tags: configuration, magento2.2.6, multi-website, scope

I have added the following data to my app/etc/config.php file:

```
'scopes' => [
    'websites' => [
        'admin' => [
            'website_id' => '0',
            'code' => 'admin',
            'name' => 'Admin',
            'sort_order' => '0',
            'default_group_id' => '0',
            'is_default' => '0'
        ],
        'website_1' => [
            'website_id' => '1',
            'code' => 'website_1',
            'name' => 'website_1',
            'sort_order' => '0',
            'default_group_id' => '1',
            'is_default' => '1'
        ],
        'website_2' => [
            'website_id' => '2',
            'code' => 'website_2',
            'name' => 'website_2',
            'sort_order' => '0',
            'default_group_id' => '2',
            'is_default' => '0'
        ]
    ],
    'groups' => [
        [
            'group_id' => '0',
            'website_id' => '0',
            'name' => 'Default',
            'root_category_id' => '0',
            'default_store_id' => '0',
            'code' => 'default'
        ],
        [
            'group_id' => '1',
            'website_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'group_1',
            'root_category_id' => '2',
            'default_store_id' => '1',
            'code' => 'group_1'
        ],
        [
            'group_id' => '2',
            'website_id' => '2',
            'name' => 'group_2',
            'root_category_id' => '2',
            'default_store_id' => '2',
            'code' => 'group_2'
        ]
    ],
    'stores' => [
        'admin' => [
            'store_id' => '0',
            'code' => 'admin',
            'website_id' => '0',
            'group_id' => '0',
            'name' => 'Admin',
            'sort_order' => '0',
            'is_active' => '1'
        ],
        'en_gb' => [
            'store_id' => '1',
            'code' => 'store_1',
            'website_id' => '1',
            'group_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'store_1',
            'sort_order' => '0',
            'is_active' => '1'
        ],
        'store_2' => [
            'store_id' => '2',
            'code' => 'store_2',
            'website_id' => '2',
            'group_id' => '2',
            'name' => 'store_2',
            'sort_order' => '0',
            'is_active' => '1'
        ]
    ]
]
```

When running the the following CI command:

`php bin/magento app:config:import`

I am greeted with the following helpful error message:

```
$ php bin/magento app:config:import --no-interaction
Processing configurations data from configuration file...
Import failed: Validation Failed
```

Has anyone come across this issue before know how I can determine why the validation failed?

I've checked the logs and found nothing of use apart from the same super helpful error message repeated.

Comment: are you able to resolve this issue? I am having the same. Please help here